# How do I counter the Cursed Inferno debuff?

Tags: terraria

Is there an accessory or potion that will give me immunity (perhaps temporarily) to the [Cursed Inferno](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cursed_Inferno) debuff?

Comment: I don't think that there is an accessory or buff for this yet, I could be wrong though. Maybe someone will provide a solid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no accessory or buff that will protect you from Cursed Inferno. The only winning move is not to get hit by cursed flames.

Comment: A strange reference.